# Using Lua to call C (in Linux)

Tags: lua

I made a C program and wrote the following two function in that

```
1. int c_add(lua_State* L)  
   {...some code here...  
   }  
2. int main(int argc, char* argv)  
   {...some code here...  
   lua_register(L, "c_add", c_add);  
   }
```

And compiled it by following command successfully.

```
gcc -o test.exe test.c -I /home/ec2-user/install/lua-5.1.5/src -llua-5.1
```

But the following error showed after using a lua program to call it.

```
lua: func2.lua:2: attempt to call global 'c_add' (a nil value)
```

How to solve this problem?`

Comment: What is the file `func2.lua` and how are you running it?

Comment: @cyclaminist thank you for reply. The code is here.
`-- func2.lua`
`print(c_add(3,4))`

Comment: @cyclaminist
And I run it by `lua func2.lua`.

Comment: `lua.exe` is not the `test.exe`. You have `c_add` function defined by the code in `test.exe`, so you must run `func2.lua` from within the `test.exe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile the code as a shared library to access the C functions from an external Lua instance. You don't need the `main` function and you pass the `-shared` flag to gcc. Then you need to let Lua know what to do when `require` is called by implementing the following function:

```
//             same name as the so/dll
//                      v
LUALIB_API int luaopen_test(lua_State *L) {
    lua_register(L, "c_add", c_add);
    return 0;
}
```

This creates a single, global function. It's better to register a `luaL_Reg` array of functions with `luaL_register`:

```
static const luaL_Reg function_list[] = {
    {"c_add",   c_add},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

LUALIB_API int luaopen_test(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_register(L, "test", function_list);
    return 1;
}
```

So that a table of functions is returned by `require`:

```
local my_c_functions = require("test")
print(my_c_functions.c_add(42, 42))
```

Comment: Thank you. I now have a deeper understanding of this. But a new error appeared when I using the code above.  
`lua: error loading module 'test' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/test.so':`  
`/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/test.so: undefined symbol: luaL_register`  
  Does it means I have to include come library in C program?

Comment: `luaL_register` is from Lua 5.1. In Lua 5.3, `luaL_register` is not defined unless you have compiled Lua with `LUA_COMPAT_MODULE` defined, so if you are compiling your library for Lua 5.3, it would be better to replace `luaL_register(L, "test", function_list)` with `luaL_newlib(L, function_list)` (and to make sure you are using the Lua 5.3 versions of the Lua headers).

Comment: @cyclaminist
Thank you for detailed explanation.
I've replaced the function by following your advice, but the next error appeared.
`lua: error loading module 'test' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/test.so':`
`/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/test.so: undefined symbol: luaopen_test`
But there is no "luaopen_test" in my source code.

Comment: As PaulR explained above, your library needs a function for the Lua VM to call when you `require` the library from Lua. In this case, the function needs to be named `luaopen_test`. See the documentation for [package.searchers](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers) for more information.